# Rotate Object using rotational matrix around different origin? (java)

Tags: java, matrix, rotation

I am using the rotation to rotate a rectangle I have displaying on the screen by a degree of 
θ°. My rectangle matrix of vertices is:

[image: my rectangle matrix of vertices]

Where the first column is the x values and the second column is the y values. I load my vertices like this: **bottomLeft (2,4), topLeft (2,5), topRight (3,5), and finally bottomRight (3,4)**.

Next I multiply it against the rotation matrix:

[image: rotation matrix]

Finally once the calculation is done, I get a new set of vertices:

[image: new set of vertices]

This is great and all but a problem is here, it rotates around the **center point of (0,0)**. I want it to rotate around my **bottomLeft vertex (2,4)** (the first vertex in my matrix for this rectangle). How do I go about doing this? What do I have to do to rotate it around my bottomLeft vertex (basically change the *center point of (0,0) to (2,4) as my center*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rotations will be done around the origin, so you have to move your rectangle to the origin, rotate it, then move it back.

If you use [Affine Transforms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) you can do all three with matrix multiplications, and you can have a single matrix that does all three operations at once. If your rotation matrix must stay 2x2 then you'll have to do the translation (i.e. move) manually.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337060/rotation-of-point-in-3d-space/5337219#5337219) shows how to compose the transforms for a point rotation.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said, I moved it to the origin, rotated it and moved it back. Worked just fine. Ill also look at affine transforms. Thanks again