# How do you create a custom axis to rotate a mesh in Three.js without altering the mesh's X,Y,Z origin point?

Tags: rotation, three.js

I have a collection of "blocks" that are Three.js (r72) mesh objects (mostly created from extruded shapes)

[image]

This mesh's bounding box is a `1 x 1 x 1` cube, the XYZ axis helper is at `0,0,0`, and after this shape was created it was **added** to the scene at `1,1,0`.
So to clarify, the mesh's `0,0,0` is at the world `1,1,0`.

I want to rotate the object around the Z axis (Blue Axis) (e.g. in the XY plane) such that the curved face is facing me.

If I do so, it rotates around the Z axis, specifically at the mesh's origin point and I get this.
[image]

However this is ***NOT*** what I want at all.

I want to rotate the mesh around **a** Z-Axis, specifically the one that runs through the **centroid** of my mesh. e.g. an axis formed by the *current* world co-ordinates `1.5,1.5,0` to `1.5,1.5,1`.

Thus the resulting output would be (I had to fake this to get the desired image)
[image]

I am aware that I can create my initial shape/mesh so that the "insertion point"/origin is actually at the centroid (or bottom center) of my shape and thus this would "solve" my rotation issue but I do not want to do that as it will ruin the ability for me to place the blocks in a simple, logical manner.

I'm OK with whatever option works for this, whether applying a matrix transformation, or rotation.

The only ***ugly*** option I could come up with was to:

- Save the `orig.x, orig.y, orig.z` of the mesh's insertion point
- Move the mesh to `((0,0,0) - (meshCentroid.x, meshCentroid.y, meshCentroid.z))`
- Rotate the mesh around the World `Z Axis`
- Move the mesh back `((orig.x, orig.y, orig.z) + (meshCentroid.x, meshCentroid.y, meshCentroid.z))`

However this seems like extreme overkill, and won't work if I want to rotate around an arbitrary axis other than the one that passes through the centroid.

I'm aware that there are many similar questions already asked here, but all the one's I've found ***ruin the position point of the mesh*** in order to apply the rotation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953608/rotate-object-on-specific-axis-anywhere-in-three-js-including-outside-of-mesh/32038265#32038265

Comment: @WestLangley ah ha! bingo that's it! I'm not even sure what the magic is that makes that work, but it certainly works.

Comment: That's why we have upvotes. ; - )