# Three JS rotation on specific axis

Tags: three.js, gsap

How can I have an ThreeJS object rotate on an axis that is at angle.

Like from this codepen I made, the left square rotates on its center and moved up when you click on the "rotate up" button.

I want the left cure rotate along the red axis in the image attached and move along on that axis when click on the "Rotate 45 degree" button.  I can make up move along the axis, but the rotation is wrong. How can I make the cute rotate along the red axis?

****EDIT:

[image]

PS: Sorry I cannot get the snippet working here. Please use the codepen link for the demo.
https://codepen.io/eforblue/pen/MWpYggY

```js
var upTl = gsap.timeline();
var degreeTl = gsap.timeline();

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
scene.add(cube);


var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
cube2.position.set(200, 200, 0);
cube2.rotation.z = 45;
scene.add(cube2);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 500, 3000);
camera.lookAt(cube.position);

scene.add(camera);

var skyboxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
var skyboxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, side: THREE.BackSide });
var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(skyboxGeometry, skyboxMaterial);


var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position.set(0, 300, 200);

scene.add(pointLight);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        
        // cube.rotation.y -= clock.getDelta();
        
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();

$('.up').on('click', () => {
  console.log('click')
     upTl.to( cube.rotation, 1, { y: Math.PI * 3 }, 0 )
     .to( cube.position, 1, { y: cube.position.y + 400 }, 0 )    
})

$('.degree').on('click', () => {
  degreeTl.to( cube2.rotation, 1, { y: Math.PI * 3 }, 0 )
     .to( cube2.position, 1, { x: cube2.position.x + 300, y:cube2.position.y + 300 }, 0 )    
});
```

```css
canvas {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
}

button {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
<button class="up">rotate up</button>
<button class="degree">rotate 45deg</button>
```

Comment: I see no attachment or red axis...

Comment: sorry, i forgot to upload the image. Just edited.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's easier to use quaternions to rotate around your red axis, you can use the following function and define your rotation axis in the "axis" parameter.

```
static rotateAroundWorldAxis(mesh, point, axis, angle) {
     const q = new Quaternion();
     q.setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);
     mesh.applyQuaternion(q);
     mesh.position.sub(point);
     mesh.position.applyQuaternion(q);
     mesh.position.add(point);
    return mesh;
}
```

Comment: Do NOT instantiate a new quaternion every call. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32038265/1461008) instead.

Comment: if it's to integrate the function to the 3D object, I agree ! thanks